# attempt to compare number with string (Lua)

Tags: lua

I've been programming this

```
io.write("How many languages do you speak?\n")

answer = io.read()

if (answer == 1)
then
io.write("You're a monolingual beta")
elseif (answer == 2)
 then
 io.write("You're bilingual")
elseif (answer == 3)
 then
 io.write("You're a multilingual semichad")
elseif (answer == 4)
 then
 io.write("You're a polyglot")
elseif (answer == 5)
 then
 io.write("You're a super polyglot")
elseif (answer == 6)
 then
 io.write("You're an hyper polyglot")
elseif (answer == 7)
 then
 io.write("You're a ultra polyglot")
elseif (answer == 8)
 then
 io.write("You're a mega polyglot")
elseif (answer == 9)
 then
 io.write("You're an ultra-mega polyglot")
elseif (answer >= 10)
 then
 io.write("You're an infinite polyglot gigachad")
end
```

But when i try to execute it and i put a number, it just says the error in the title. The line of code which the error refers is this one

```
elseif (answer >= 10)
```

And i can't really understand the issue. There are no strings. Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Better use an array for the strings instead of an if chain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`answer` variable contains a string as the result of `io.read()` call. Either add `tonumber` around `io.read()` or use `io.read("n")` to get a number.

Comment: `io.read("n", "l")`

Comment: I think i'll use the second one

Answer (score 2):

To add an explanation as to how the error comes into being:

`io.read()` reads a string (a line). `answers` thus holds the age in string form.

Lua's comparisons are strict; all equality comparisons of strings against numbers fail since strings and numbers are of different types. It eventually falls through to `answer >= 10` which throws the error since all ordering relations (`<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`) only accept either two strings or two numbers (or two tables with metatables, excepting `debug.setmetatable` for the sake of simplicity).

`answer >= 10` where `answer` is a string finally throws the error.

Comment: This is right. I really needed this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common mistake made by many people. It's especially common if you're coming from languages with less strict typing rules. However, Lua is slightly stricter, and that's better.

The thing is that `"1"` and `1` are different things - The former is a string, which represents text, whereas the latter is a number, which obviously represents a number.

In fact, they're encoded differently. The string can be considered to be encoded like this:

```
00110001
```

Whereas the number can be considered to be encoded like this:

```
00000001
```

In reality, a number is a double precision floating point number, which does cool stuff with scientific notation. However, that doesn't change the fact that in binary, these are different.

The bit-level difference aside, the types are different - if the types are different, the values are not equal, like the types. And that is why you get the error: You need a number and a number.

The solution is to use `tonumber`, which converts a string representing an integer (decimal by default, other bases disallow integers).

Comment: I don't come from less strict programming languages. I come from C, which is very strict. As you know, there you need to declare the type of variable (int,float, long or double) and that's it. Anyways, thanks!! But i don't know where to put tonumber

Comment: @TheXXcoder forgot to mention that `tonumber` is a function, you call it. I instantly thought of that common misconception when I saw incorrect types with operators, a prejudgment. And as others mentioned, `io.read("n")` exists, which I didn't know about.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the value of answer to a number. You can do so by using `tonumber(answer)`.

Comment: It throws me back an error again. Also, i don't know where to put it

Comment: If this throws an error, your answer is not a number and tonumber returns nil