# My program isn't working, the result is nothing

Tags: lua

For some reason my program isn't working and I don't know why.

```
io.write("Enter in your age: ")
local ans = io.read()
if ans >= 19 then
    print("You are allowed to drink in Canada.")
elseif ans < 19 then
    print("You are not allowed to drink in Canada")
end
```

The program is meant to detect if you are allowed to consume alcohol in Canada.

I expected it to ask you what your age was, you'd enter it in and it'd give you a result depending on what you typed in.

The result is nothing.

Comment: Actually, you are allowed to consume alcohol in Quebec if you are 18 years old ;)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73532962/107090

Answer (score 0):

The [io.read](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-io.read) produces string variable, so we need to change it to number for comparison:

```lua
local ans = tonumber(io.read(), 10)
```

Comment: No need to add the base: 10 is the default.

Comment: @lhf Yes, but if something that is given to `tonumber` produces list instead raw variable, the second list member will be interpreted as base for it. It is safer to give 10 to every `tonumber` call.

Comment: @LeszekMazur if that was your goal, another pair of parentheses would work just as well: `tonumber((io.read())` will truncate the result of `io.read()` to the first return value. Besides, `io.read()` does not return a vararg.

Comment: @Luatic Yes, that should work as well. Just it is good for me to have habit to make sure `tonumber` works as expected. I had too many issues with it.